# Clean up a collection of BitmapSource

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapsource

i have a collection of BitmapSource that are created by setting its StreamSource property to a MemoryStream of byte array. How do i remove them from memory after using them?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just clear your references to them, the garbage collector will take care of reclaiming the memory.

Comment: Hi, how do i know if it is already cleared from the memory? I tried to force a GC.Collect() but the memory doesnt seems to reduce? is collection.Clear() and collection = null sufficent? or loop through the collection and set bitmapSource = null?

Comment: @icube, `collection.Clear()` should be enough if the images are not referenced anywhere else.